# Is it safe to search a TreeView in another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, treeview

I have a TreeView and i add nodes to it in another thread using BackgroundWorker for that i had to make Invokes and now i was wondering if i have to make Invokes for search functions also like the BackgroundWorker uses the tree to search for a specific Node or is this not needed?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you dont alter the `TreeView` from a background thread (add, delete, update, etc..) then there shouldn't be a proble. Invoke is nessaccery when one needs to change a control bound to the UI thread from a background thread.